# Tensor variable indexing

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying to make some symbolic calculations using indexing of symbolic variable.

```
X = T.matrix('X')
y = T.matrix('y')
z = T.dot(T.dot(X,y[0]),y[1]).norm(L=2)
callable_function = theano.function([y,X], z)
callable_function(np.array([np.array([[3],[5]]),np.array([[4,1]])]),np.array([1,2]))
```

And I'm getting

```
AttributeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "C:/Users/LIKAN/PycharmProjects/deepEEG/test.py:17"  at index 0(0-based)', "'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'")
```

How to use symbolic variable indexing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You declare both `y` and `X` as matrices but your inputs to the compiled Theano function are an object array and a vector.

`np.array([np.array([[3],[5]]),np.array([[4,1]])])` is an object array because it is constructed as an array of numpy arrays. Note that `np.array([np.array([[3],[5]]),np.array([[4,1]])]).dtype == object`.

To create a matrix, just use a multi-dimensional array in the numpy array construction. You don't even need to create numpy arrays, just pass vanilla Python lists. Since your second argument (for `X`) is a vector I've assumed the input value is correct and the symbolic variable declaration is incorrect. With these changes, the following code runs:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

X = T.vector('X')
y = T.matrix('y')
z = T.dot(T.dot(X,y[0]),y[1]).norm(L=2)
callable_function = theano.function([y,X], z)
print callable_function([[3,5],[4,1]], [1,2])
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still have a trouble. I need that y was a list (array) of matrices, and X was a matrix.

Comment: Theano doesn't support lists. If all the matrices have the same shape then you could combine them all together into a `tensor3`. Alternatively, if you know how many matrices there will be in the list, just pass them as separate inputs to the Theano function.